# boost time_facet causes an exception that cannot be caught

Tags: c++, boost

Here is a simple example of the application

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto date = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

        // boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"); --> this format works
        boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%d-%b-%Y %k:%M:%s"); // --> this format causes an exception that can't be handled
        std::stringstream ss;

        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), facet));
        //ss.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
        ss << date; // --> exception occurs here - It can't be caught.
        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "std::exception " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::exception&)
    {
        std::cerr << "boost::exception " << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "unknown exception" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with a certain format passed to the facet - either %k or %l cause the issue.   When a date is formatted using this format there is an exception. The exception is not caught by the exception handler - the program exits!

I am creating a library function so I need to assume invalid format strings will happen.  I am ok with an exception - I just need to be able to handle it and report the error, or confirm that the facet is valid before using it.

This happens on Windows 10.  The error is in the wcsftime function.  Also wcsftime is a wide char function, and I am using 8 bit char.  The application is compiled in Visual Studio 2017 with MultiByte character set rather than Unicode.

[image: Error from debugger]

The issue occurs in the debugger with the above assertion.  Running the release build from the command line causes the application to crash and pop up the 'Application has stopped working' windows dialog.

The boost version is 1.65.1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's an assertion, not an exception. An assertion means a bug.

Comment: You cannot catch assertion errors. (Well, you probably could, but not like exceptions, and you shouldn't.) Assertions are there to detect programmers' mistakes, you are supposed to fix the bug, not recover from it on runtime.

Comment: I don't see any way to check whether a format is valid beforehand, through Boost or through `strftime`. It's unfortunate that there would be an assertion with no easy way to prevent firing it. It's likely that the format was intended to be a hardcoded thing rather than something built using unknown input. From the assertion condition, it appears that the implementation is not checking it up front either, likely because it would duplicate a chunk of work that the function already has to do.

Comment: I suppose the easy way to prevent the assertion is to compile Release mode and link release version of the runtime library. (With the net effect of e.g. definining `-DNDEBUG`)

Comment: If you do use the release version, you'll likely end up with undefined behaviour instead of the assertion. It's not really any better. However, given that it's `assert(false)`, it might be the case that the code is structured to have no ill effects with an invalid format string. That's still a pretty risky assumption.

Comment: Usually with an assert if you ignore there will then be an exception which you can catch, not necessarily safely as something may be corrupt.  This one aborts the process regardless for some reason. I guess boost does something unsafe with the wcsftime function that causes an unrecoverable buffer overrun or similar.   Either way I think it is a bug in boost or wcsftime.   I'll need to look at a different library.

Comment: Here is the reason for the issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/parameter-validation

The problem also happens with std::chrono too if you pass a bad format string. It looks like I will need to support only fixed string formats.

Comment: You might try [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) which has extensive parsing facilities.  If you don't require anything but the "C" locale, it can even be configured to bypass `wcsftime` by turning on the macro `ONLY_C_LOCALE`.  It is also easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you're doing wrong is using MBCS...  Definitely not recommended.  Windows' native string format is UNICODE, and all functions ending with A transform the input strings, then call their W counterparts.

Why the call to new?  There surely is enough space on the stack for the time format.

Anyway, the dialog you are seeing shows a assertion failed message.  It is a debug breakpoint (`__asm int 3;`), not an exception.  It also is only present in the debug version of the runtime library.

You should try compiling a release build, or hitting the 'ignore' button and watch your app catching the exception.

[edit] after investigation, strftime() causes the app to crash. An invalid format string is considered a fatal error by the C runtime library.  Go figure why, but that's the way it is.

Comment: Hitting the ignore button causes a crash in debug. Also I tried both Unicode and MBCS as I thought this may have been the problem.

Comment: Let a note be made, which shall read: "Passing an ill-formed formatting string to `boost::posix_time::time_facet`'s constructor leads to undefined behavior.".  As further indicated by the assertion break in the code.